# Does Ubuntu have an option to show open programs only on the monitor its open on?

Tags: multiple-monitors

I know there is a plugin for this for windows and I am not sure about Ubuntu (since I am new to it).

Anyway I am working with two screens and I want to show the open programs on the screen they are open on.

Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: Not sure what the question aims on: in the launcher?

Comment: yes, however i am no longer new to ubuntu, and i understand that there is an arrow on the screen that the program is open on in the launcher